# Input into site using Mechanize (Python)

Tags: python, html, browser, mechanize

I'm trying to make a dictionary program using dictionary.com for the source but I can't find the name of the search box in the source code

```
from mechanize import Browser

inp = raw_input("Enter Word: ")
Word = (inp)

SEARCH_PAGE = "http://dictionary.reference.com/"

browser = Browser()
browser.open( SEARCH_PAGE )
browser.select_form( nr=0 ) 

browser['name of search form'] = Word
browser.submit()
```

Can anyone help me make this work or help me find the name of the search bar in the HTML source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look through the forms with the method Browser.forms().
Each of these forms has a variable called controls,
a list of controls in the form.
Each control in this list has a "name" variable.
You can use these names to index with the browser, as you already know.

```
from mechanize import Browser

inp = raw_input("Enter Word: ")
Word = (inp)

SEARCH_PAGE = "http://dictionary.reference.com/"

browser = Browser()
browser.open( SEARCH_PAGE )

form = list(browser.forms())[0]                        #The first form
print form
names = map(lambda n: n.name, form.controls)
print names

browser.select_form( nr=0 ) 

browser[names[0]] = Word

txt = browser.submit().read()

#txt has the html from dictionary.reference.com
```